# I cant get the google analytics example to work, PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

So I'm trying to create a web app that will let users view data from many different google analytics accounts. So they could enter someones credentials (however that works) and then have an option to take the data for that account and print it out in a .pdf or something similar.

My first question is this, is it even possible to manage multiple analytics accounts from one place? I have been searching for days but am still not sure if this is even possible.

And the other question would be this. I'm trying to get there Hello Analytics Reporting API v4; PHP quick start for web applications Demo to work on my site, but for the life of me cant seem to get it working all the way. everything works fine until I click "Allow" button on the google sign in form. Instead of returning to the original file and displaying the data it just starts a loop of asking me if I want to allow this website to use my data.

(EDIT)
So now instead of looping through over and over again, once if log in to google it sends me to an error page that displays this.

ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

I tried clearing my cookies but that didn't help.

And yes I have the Google API PHP Client Library in the same folder.

This is my code (NOTE, I have placed everything in a dir called "testing").

index.php

```
<?php

// Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
require_once __DIR__ . '/google-api-php-client-2.2.1/vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/client_secrets.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);


// If the user has already authorized this app then get an access token
// else redirect to ask the user to authorize access to Google Analytics.
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
    // Set the access token on the client.
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

    // Create an authorized analytics service object.
    $analytics = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting($client);

    // Call the Analytics Reporting API V4.
    $response = getReport($analytics);

    // Print the response.
    printResults($response);

} else {
    $redirect_uri = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/testing/oauth2callback.php';
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}


/**
 * Queries the Analytics Reporting API V4.
 *
 * @param service An authorized Analytics Reporting API V4 service object.
 * @return The Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
 */
function getReport($analytics) {

    // Replace with your view ID, for example XXXX.
    $VIEW_ID = "170811711";

    // Create the DateRange object.
    $dateRange = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_DateRange();
    $dateRange->setStartDate("7daysAgo");
    $dateRange->setEndDate("today");

    // Create the Metrics object.
    $sessions = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_Metric();
    $sessions->setExpression("ga:sessions");
    $sessions->setAlias("sessions");

    // Create the ReportRequest object.
    $request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
    $request->setViewId($VIEW_ID);
    $request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
    $request->setMetrics(array($sessions));

    $body = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_GetReportsRequest();
    $body->setReportRequests( array( $request) );
    return $analytics->reports->batchGet( $body );
}


/**
 * Parses and prints the Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
 *
 * @param An Analytics Reporting API V4 response.
 */
function printResults($reports) {
    for ( $reportIndex = 0; $reportIndex < count( $reports ); $reportIndex++ ) {
        $report = $reports[ $reportIndex ];
        $header = $report->getColumnHeader();
        $dimensionHeaders = $header->getDimensions();
        $metricHeaders = $header->getMetricHeader()->getMetricHeaderEntries();
        $rows = $report->getData()->getRows();

        for ( $rowIndex = 0; $rowIndex < count($rows); $rowIndex++) {
            $row = $rows[ $rowIndex ];
            $dimensions = $row->getDimensions();
            $metrics = $row->getMetrics();
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($dimensionHeaders) && $i < count($dimensions); $i++) {
                print($dimensionHeaders[$i] . ": " . $dimensions[$i] . "\n");
            }

            for ($j = 0; $j < count($metrics); $j++) {
                $values = $metrics[$j]->getValues();
                for ($k = 0; $k < count($values); $k++) {
                    $entry = $metricHeaders[$k];
                    print($entry->getName() . ": " . $values[$k] . "\n");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ouath2callback.php

```
<?php

// Load the Google API PHP Client Library.
require_once __DIR__ . '/google-api-php-client-2.2.1/vendor/autoload.php';

// Start a session to persist credentials.
session_start();

// Create the client object and set the authorization configuration
// from the client_secrets.json you downloaded from the Developers Console.
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__ . '/client_secrets.json');
$client->setRedirectUri('https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/testing/oauth2callback.php');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);

// Handle authorization flow from the server.
if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $redirect_uri = 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/testing/index.php';
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

So basically it looks like it losses the $_SESSION['access_token'] when it goes back to index.php, which makes it go back to ouath2callback.php to get them over and over again.

Thanks, Luc

Comment: Did you grab that sample code form the Google analytics docs?

Comment: Yes, everything is straight from this page https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-php. the only exception being the files paths are slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

You have not set your view id. You can get this by looking here https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/account-explorer/

```
 $VIEW_ID = "<REPLACE_WITH_VIEW_ID>";
```

Comment: I saw this and replaced it with my view I'd and it still didn't work. I can't figure out how to update a question though so I just let it like this. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Have updated it for you. Go into your error log and give us the latest error which should help. Also, do you have these directories within your testing folder /google-api-php-client-2.2.1/vendor/ ?